# How do you reference a layer from an core animation object?

Tags: ios, caanimation

I am trying to animate the scaling of an image from 0 to 1.  The animation is delayed, so I need the initial image to either be scaled to 0, or have its layer's hidden property set.  And then either when the animation finishes, set the scale to 1 (so it doesn't revert back to its initially defined 0 scaling) OR when the animation begins, unset the layer's hidden property.

So..  I have not been able to find any information on how to accomplish either of those approaches, and also I am curious if there is a better way to do what I am trying to do.

If I set the animation's delegate, and make use of the animationDidStart or animationDidStop methods, I am given a CAAnimation object, and I have not been able to figure out how to get access to the layer being animated from that object.

I was really hoping these animation objects just would have a beforeStart, afterFinish properties that takes a block, but apparently they do not.

Answer (score 0):

You can take reference of ImageView in your .h file as an instance variable. Then in `animation didStart` you can access layer of ImageView.

```
//.h File

UIImageView *imgVAnimated;


//.m File

//I'm not sure about the proper method name just for demonstration purpose I'm using the below one

- (void) animationDidStart {
imgVAnimated.layer = //Whatever you want to do
}
```